# Open Existing QMainWindow from QMainWindow

Tags: qt, qtgui, qmainwindow, qt-signals

I have a little question - I have QMainWindow with button. On click on that button I would like an existing QMainWindow to open (detail: I want open a window with QWT Plot. I mean the refreshtest project example of QWt.)

So I would like to existing Window open on button. As far I was able to open new QMainWindow, but what can I do to see MainWindow from project refreshtest?

```
void  MyWindow::on_pushButton_1_clicked ()
{
  QMainWindow *mw = new QMainWindow();
  mw->show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With this code, you will get a leaking pointer after leaving the scope of the method.

The reason is that the show() method is not blocking. It will post an event into the event loop queue. It will get processed in an async manner whenever the Qt event loop "gets the capacity for that".

You have several options to address this issue.

1) Qt parent/child relation

```
QMainWindow *mw = new QMainWindow(this);
                                  ^^^^
```

2) Make "mw" a class member of MyWindow

```
m_mw.show();
```

and construct it in the MyWindow constructor.

3) Use a smart pointer

```
QSharedPointer<QMainWindow> mw = QSharedPointer<QMainWindow>(new QMainWindow());
```